# How to remove tooltip when user visits the page for the first time?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I want to show a tooltip and a bubble over a **router-link** when the user logs in for the first time and remove it when he visited the page.

Routing is already set up and works fine. Inside my **App.vue**:

```
<template>
    <div id="app" >
        <div id="nav">
           <router-link to="/home">Home</router-link>
          
           <router-link to="/User">{{$t('user-text')}}

                <div class="tooltip">
                    <span class="badge">!</span>
                    <span class="tooltiptext">{{ $t('visit-page-for-first-time') }}</span>
                </div>

            </router-link>
        </div>

    </div>
</template>
```

The tooltip is showing up but doesn't disappear at the moment. How would I remove it when the user visits the page at least one time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a cookie or local storage flag to determine if a user has been to that page before.

An example using local storage:

```
<template>
    <div id="app" >
        <div id="nav">
           <router-link to="/home">Home</router-link>
      
           <router-link to="/User">{{$t('user-text')}}

               <div class="tooltip">
                   <span class="badge">!</span>
                   <span class="tooltiptext" v-if="showTooltip">{{ $t('visit-page-for-first-time') }}</span>
               </div>

           </router-link>
        </div>

    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                showTooltip: false
            }
        },

        created() {
            const alreadyVisited = localStorage.getItem('already_visited');

            if (!alreadyVisited) {
                this.showTooltip = true;

                this.setAlreadyVisited();
            }
        },
    
        methods: {
            setAlreadyVisited() {
                localStorage.setItem('already_visited', true)
            }
        },

        watch: {
            $route (to, from) {
                this.showTooltip = false;
            }
        } 
    }
</script>
```

This will, by default hide the tooltip. Then in the `created` hook we check if the localStorage item with the key of `already_visited` exists and if it doesn't we show the tooltip. Otherwise we leave it unrendered.

Comment: Nice catch with local storage! Right now it doesn't show the tooltip at all. Don't we have to set the item before we get it?

Comment: Nevermind, it works when I manually reload the page but not when I select another page.

Comment: Can you tell how to remove the tooltip when you change the route without reloading the whole page?

Comment: do you use vuex in your projects?

Comment: Yeah, im using vuex

Comment: that last question I asked turns out to be redundant, I think you just need to use a watcher to monitor when the route changes and react by setting the `showTooltip` value back to false, I have updated my answer with an example

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to use a couple of methods which toggle the opacity (or display, however you want) on `mouseover` and `mouseout`:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  methods: {
    showTooltip() {
      this.$refs.tooltip.style.opacity = '1';
    },
    hideTooltip() {
      this.$refs.tooltip.style.opacity = '0';
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.tooltip {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div id="nav">
    <a href="/home">Home</a>
    <a href="/User" @mouseover="showTooltip()" @mouseout="hideTooltip()">user-text
        <div class="tooltip" ref="tooltip">
            <span class="badge">!</span>
            <span class="tooltiptext">visit-page-for-first-time</span>
        </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've used `<a>` tags here but with `<router-link>` you have to use the `.native` event modifier like this:

```
<router-link to="/User" @mouseover.native="showTooltip()" @mouseout.native="hideTooltip()">
```